# Not able to convert the datetime stored as a string to Datetime within a IList

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-web-api, lambda, datetime-format

I'm working on an WebApi which receives the data from database using Lambda and storing in a IList. The output I'm getting has a dataformat as `"2018-04-20T14:39:20.01"`. But I want to show the date format as "`20-Apr-2018 / 02:39:20 PM"`.

Once i get the output, I'm manipulated the date and converted to the format which I wanted that are stored as a string.

Now when I'm trying to send that data back to the IList, am getting error saying that the String is not recognized as a valid datetime.

```
string val = statusSourceType1[0].updatedDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt").ToString();
                #1
                statusSourceType1[0].updatedDate = DateTime.Parse(val);
                #2
                statusSourceType1[0].updatedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(val, "dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                #3
                statusSourceType1[0].updatedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(val, "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
```

In the above code, first line converts the dateformat from  `2018-04-20T14:39:20.01` to `15-Apr-2018 12:23:21 PM`.

Once the conversion is done, I want to convert the string value into datatime and pass with the output since my UI is expecting the datetime and not string.

While converting the string to datetime, either Am getting the runtime error "String is not recognized as a valid datetime" or the datetime format gets back to its original state.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

> "...datetime stored as a string..."

There's your problem right there.
You are working in a WebApi and your UI is expecting a DateTime, not a string. So why do you bother to convert the date to string and back?

`DateTime` does not have a display format - only string representations of it does.

Just send the UI an instance of the `DateTime` struct and let the UI handle the display format - that's the UI's responsibility, not the server.

Comment: Point taken @Zohar. I conveyed the same to my Architect and he believes that all the data manipulation need to be done in API and not in UI..,:(

Comment: That's not data manipulation - you do not change the value of the date time, only the way it's represented to the human client - and in any case you have no way of controlling the display format on the server, if your client is receiving an instance of the `DateTime` struct - as I wrote - `DateTime` does not store display format.

Answer (score 0):

try setting culture if you need

```
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

then try

```
  dt.ToString("dd/MMMM/yyyy"); //or whichever
```

As your comment. Answer simple question, if you set 1112018 as `date` using `ddmmyyyy` how can you expect to get the conversion working back to datatime. You app design is not right, let the `View` do the formatting and pass the dt obj

OR

make you `View` to expect string version of dt

Comment: Converting the datetime to string works as expecting @Alex. My problem comes when Im trying to set the string back to datetime which my UI is expecting.

Comment: @UdhayaS how can you do this? You may set any format using `ToString()`

Comment: Im working on the same. Thank you for your input Jim.